# I can't find the voice File > New > Titanium project

Tags: titanium

I use Titanium Studio 3.2 on Win 7 64. I'm trying to follow the book "Appcelerator Titanium Application Development by Example Beginner's Guide" by Darren Cope (2013). Talking about MVC (pg. 66) the author says to create a new Titanium Project from menu "File > New > Titanium Project" but I don't have this voice. Obviously I tried to seek for it in the other submenus... That missing voice allows to create a demo app splitted on various files
(from the book:
resources/app.js The app.js file and nothing else
resources/ui/common Common code across all platforms for
business logic
resources/ui/handheld/android Android phone specific layout code
resources/ui/handheld/ios iPhone-specific layout code
resources/ui/handheld/mobileweb Browser-based HTML5 specific layout
code
resources/ui/tablet Android and iOS tablet layout
).
Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The book has written before the release of newer versions of Titanium Studio. In earlier versions, we were able to create new project as written in the book.

To create a new Project in Titanium Studio 3.2, you need go as follows

```
File->New->Mobile App Project
```

This will display a new window as in figure 1.

[image: figure 1]

If you want to create a project in Alloy, select an option from the Alloy or if you want to create a classic application, select the classic tab which will display a dialog as in figure 2.

[image]

Select the type of your project and click next. Provide details required and click finish button. Your project will be created.

You can get more information from the [official documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start-section-37538717_QuickStart-HelloTitaniumApp).

It would be recommended to use [Appcelerator documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api) itself to getting start with Titanium so that you'll keep up to date.